# Loop for pmax () for pairs of variables

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
varnames<-c( "aR.0", "aL.0", "aR.1", "aL.1", "aR.3", "aL.3")

a <-matrix (c(1,2,3,4, 5, 6), 2, 6)

colnames (a)<-varnames

df<-as.data.frame (a)


 a
    aR.0 aL.0 aR.1 aL.1 aR.3 aL.3
[1,]    1    3    5    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6    2    4    6
```

I need to add to the dataframe the vectors containing maximum values of pairs of variables, having:

- similar bases ("a" and "a")
- similar suffixes ("0" and "0", "1" and "1", "3" and "3")
- but different last letters before suffix (R and L).

In several lines it looks like:

```
 df$max.a.0 <- pmax(df [,"aR.0"], df[,"aL.0"])
 df$max.a.1<-pmax(df [,"aR.1"], df[,"aL.1"])
 df$max.a.3<- pmax(df [,"aR.3"], df[,"aL.3"])

df
    aR.0 aL.0 aR.1 aL.1 aR.3 aL.3 max.a.0 max.a.1 max.a.3
 1    1    3    5    1    3    5       3       5       5
 2    2    4    6    2    4    6       4       6       6
```

How to perform this task automatically? 
I racked my brain trying to write a loop without any success.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the specifics depend on the specific properties of your dataframe, which are not apparent from the example you give. For instance, you specify that bases should be similar, but there is just a single base "a". It is also unclear whether the order of those variables is always the same.

Anyway, for your current example the following approach might work:

```
df1 <- df[,grep("aR\\..",colnames(df))]
df2 <- df[,grep("aL\\..",colnames(df))]

pmax(df1,df2)
```

You could extend the same logic to the general case by (1) making the regular expressions more complex (e.g. to include other bases) and (2) by sorting the column vectors, if necessary, to achieve the identical order required for `pmax()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much, Maxim. K! This is exactly what I wanted. You saved me from typing about 60 lines of code.